# Regex Pattern Works only if there is One [URL] Tag

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex pattern to get values from `[URL=http://www.google.com]Google[/URL]`

```
$pattern = '/\[\s*URL(.+?)?\s*\](.+?)\[\s*\/URL\s*\]/i';
```

It works fine but only if there is only one `[URL]...[/URL]`. if there is a string having multiple `[URL]....[/URL]` it gives the wrong values

For example for the following string

```
$string = '[URL=http://www.google.com]Google[/URL] another website [URL]www.youtube.com[/URL]';
```

It outputs the first match as `]http://www.freshupnow.com[/URL` and leaves the rest URL tags.
I have tried a lot to find the problem in my regex pattern but failed. any one has idea?

Comment: You probably didn't do a global search, but need to see source to know for sure. Also your example seems to have a different URL output than input. I guess a copy/paste error.

Comment: Try something like this `$string = '[URL=http://www.google.com]Google[/URL] another website [URL]www.youtube.com[/URL]';
preg_match_all('/\[URL=(?<url>.*?)\].*?\[\/URL\]/is', $string, $m);
print_r($m["url"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL search is working as expected, that is if the /URL you have listed is incorrect, or you are matching to a different pattern than you gave us.

```
$pattern = '/\[\s*URL(.+?)?\s*\](.+?)\[\s*\/URL\s*\]/i';
```

would get

```
([URL=http://www.google.com]Google[/URL] another website [URL)
(]www.freshupnow.com)
([/URL])
```

for the RegEX above.

If you wanted it to not jump out of the system you would change your RegEx just slightly to

```
$pattern = '/\[\s*URL([^\]]+?)?\s*\](.+?)\[\s*\/URL\s*\]/i';
```

This will keep it from jumping out of the []'s when it does a pattern expression.

Comment: You could add an online demo at [regex101](http://regex101.com) for clarity